# Drawing white line

Tags: tikz-pgf, templates

I'm trying to recreate [this](https://github.com/noraj/OSCP-Exam-Report-Template-Markdown) template.
My problem is the first page, I can set the background color of the page easily, but I'm not able to draw that white line with tikz and I didn't find anything online.

How I can do it?

That's what I did:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for auto generating text
\usepackage{afterpage}% for "\afterpage"
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xspace}
\definecolor{myBlue}{RGB}{0,150,255}
\newcommand\mycolor{\color{white}\xspace}
\usepackage{pagecolor}% With option pagecolor={somecolor or none}
\begin{document}
\mycolor
\pagenumbering{gobble}
test
\newpagecolor{myBlue}\afterpage{\restorepagecolor}
\normalcolor
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please give a MWE.

Comment: Use `rule` with options, like: `\begin{document}
\mycolor
\pagenumbering{gobble}
 \rule{18cm}{2pt}
 
 test
\newpagecolor{myBlue}\afterpage{\restorepagecolor}
\normalcolor
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}`

Comment: Thank you! That did the job